# Change of variable in Schrödinger's first paper

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian-formalism, semiclassical

On the first page of his first paper in series "Quantization as an Eigenvalue Problem", [Schrödinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erwin_Schr%C3%B6dinger) begins with

> $$H(q, \frac{\partial S}{\partial q})=E$$

and then takes a change of variable that I don't understand its motivation:

> Here we now put for $S$ a new unknown $\psi$ such that it will appear as a *product* of related functions of the single co-ordinates, i.e. we put
> $$S=K\log\psi$$
> where $K$ is a constant.

The change of variable from $S$ to $\psi$ in not only for computational purpose, but it leads us to celebrated variable $\psi$. What is the motivation behind this change of variable?

Comment: Can you link it ?

Comment: The relationship between the Hamilton-Jacobi equation and geometrical optics had been known for almost a century when Schrodinger wrote his paper. He was expecting S to be related to the phase of a wave, and so was expecting the wave function to be something like $\psi = e^{\imath k S}$

Comment: [here](https://doi.org/10.1002/andp.19263840602)

Comment: Also [with translation](http://ofp.cosmo-ufes.org/uploads/1/3/7/0/13701821/quantisation_as_an_eigenvalue_problem.pdf).

Comment: Essentially his [PRD 28 paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.28.1049) hardly differs...

Answer (score 8):

> Schrodinger begins with
> $$H(q, \frac{\partial S}{\partial q})=E$$

When the symbol $S$ stands for the *action* the quantity
$$
\frac{\partial S}{\partial q} = p\;,
$$
is the momentum. (More precisely, the action here is evaluated on the classical path from some fixed point $q_0$ and time $t_0$ to the point $q$ at time $t$.)

For example, for a free particle, the action is:
$$
S_{free} = \frac{1}{2}m \frac{(q-q_0)^2}{t-t_0}
$$

> and then take a change of variable that I don't understand it's motivation... $S=K\log(\psi)$... What is the motivation behind this change of variable?!

As for an *a posteriori* motivation, it turns out that in quantum mechanics the *amplitude* to travel along a given path is:
$$
e^{S/K}\;,
$$
where, it turns out, $K=-i\hbar$, where $\hbar$ is the reduced Planck constant.

The *amplitude* is usually denoted
$$
\psi\;,
$$
so we would write
$$
\psi = e^{iS/\hbar}
$$
or
$$
\ln(\psi) = \frac{i}{\hbar}S
$$

---

As for an *a priori* motivation, the link could come from [the Hamilton-Jacobi equation and geometrical optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation#Waves_and_particles), as suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

When solving the time-independent [Hamilton-Jacobi equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation)
$$H\left(q,\frac{\partial S}{\partial q}\right)=E \tag{0}$$
you often can use additive separation of variables.
The solution is then a *sum* of functions, each depending
only on one coordinate $q_i$:
$$S(q)=\sum_i W_i(q_i) \tag{1}$$

By substituting $S(q)=K\log\psi(q)$
(or equivalently: by substituting $\psi(q)=e^{S(q)/K}$)
(1) corresponds to solutions
$$\psi(q)=\prod_i \phi_i(q_i) \tag{2}$$
where $\psi$ is a *product* of functions, each depending only
on one coordinate $q_i$.
Such a product solution looks much more like a wave function
(i.e. the solution of a still unknown linear differential equation),
which Schrödinger was looking for.

Then the differential equation for $\psi$ is "guessed" to be
$$H\left(q,K\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\right)\psi=E\psi \tag{3}$$
where $H\left(q,K\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\right)$ now is a
differential operator. This  wave equation (3) is justified
by the fact, that in  the limit $K\to 0$ it leads back to the
Hamilton-Jacobi equation (0) as an approximation.